# A Pythonic implementation of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, game-of-life

I've just finished implementing [Conway's Game of Life](http://web.stanford.edu/~cdebs/GameOfLife/) in python-3.6:

```
import curses
import numpy as np
import time

from collections import defaultdict
from enum import Enum
from typing import List


class State(Enum):
    ''' enum class to represent possible cell states '''
    dead = 0
    alive = 1


class Board:
    ''' Board class to represent the game board '''
    def __init__(self, m : int, n : int, init : List[List[int]]):
        self.m = m   # the number of rows
        self.n = n   # the number of columns
        self.board_ = [
            [State(init[i][j]) for j in range(self.n)] for i in range(self.m)
        ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        ''' return the __str__ representation of a Board object
            * represents a live cell, and a space represents a dead one
        '''
        return '\n'.join([
            ''.join(
                    ['*' if cell.value else ' ' for cell in row]
            ) for row in self.board_]
        )

    @property
    def population(self):
        ''' population — the number of live cells on the board '''
        return sum(cell.value for row in self.board_ for cell in row)

    def count_live_neighbours(self, x : int, y : int) -> int:
        ''' count the live neighbours of a cell '''
        count = 0
        for i in range(x - 1, x + 2):
            for j in range(y - 1, y + 2):
                if (i == x and j == y) or i < 0 or j < 0:
                    continue
                # handle IndexErrors raised during invalid indexing operations 
                try:
                    count += self.board_[i][j].value
                except IndexError:
                    continue

        return count

    def next_cell_state(self, x : int, y : int) -> State:
        count = self.count_live_neighbours(x, y)
        cur_state = self.board_[x][y]
        # determine the next state based on the current state and 
        # number of live neighbours 
        if count in {2, 3} and cur_state == State.alive:
            return cur_state
        elif count == 3 and cur_state == State.dead:
            return State.alive

        return State.dead

    def next_board_state(self) -> List[List[State]]: 
        ''' return board configuration for the next state '''    
        return [
            [self.next_cell_state(i, j) for j in range(self.n)] for i in range(self.m)
        ]

    def advance_state(self):
        ''' update the board configuration with the config for the next state '''
        self.board_ = self.next_board_state()

    def has_live_cells(self) -> bool:
        ''' return whether there are any live cells or not '''
        return any(cell.value for row in self.board_ for cell in row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.random.choice([0, 1], (20, 100), p=[0.90, 0.1]) 
    board = Board(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1], init=arr.tolist())

    step = 0
    while board.has_live_cells():
        step += 1
        print(board)
        print('f{step} {board.population}')
        board.advance_state()

        time.sleep(.1)
```

To run the code, just invoke `python3.6 conway.py`. The board shape is fixed; but the configuration is randomly generated with NumPy.

My aim with this project was:

1. Implement a concise and pythonic version of the algorithm
2. Get better with Python's OOP constructs
3. Kill time :-)

There are a few redundant functions and properties which felt would be useful at some point of time.

My next step with this program would likely be to host it on a server and let people run it on their browser with a Step and Run button. This might influence how I'd need to structure my code.

Comment: As a bonus, I'd like to know if/how it would be possible to print to stdout using the `curses` module (so as to overwrite the previous state's output).

Comment: Is it just me not finding it or are you actually not using your `import curses` at all at the moment?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger it's not you... that import is there pending future work. Actually, tried a couple of things and failed, forgot to remove before updating!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you're asking for pythonic? I thought _you_ were the pythonic guy!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre As the answer below indicates, I have a ways to go :p

Comment: don't believe the bit about `join` without brackets, though :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is pretty good, and there's not much I'd change. However I would change it in the following ways:

1. It's standard to use `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` for Enum values.
2. It's preferred to use [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) over [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) to annotate arguments.
3. When you have to comment what a variable is, it indicates you've chosen a bad name. Instead use `rows` over `m`.
4. Either put your comprehensions on one line or split them out.

   ```
   # Current way
   [
       [State(init[i][j]) for j in range(self.n)] for i in range(self.m)
   ]

   # One line
   [[State(init[i][j]) for j in range(self.n)] for i in range(self.m)]

   # Multiple lines
   [
       [
         State(init[i][j])
         for j in range(self.n)
       ]
       for i in range(self.m)
   ]
   ```
5. It's easier to read a comprehension in a function if you keep the brackets together.

   ```
   # Current
   return '\n'.join([
       ''.join(
               ['*' if cell.value else ' ' for cell in row]
       ) for row in self.board_]
   )

   # Together
   return '\n'.join([
       ''.join(['*' if cell.value else ' '
                for cell in row])
           for row in self.board_])

   # Together and multiple lines
   return '\n'.join([
       ''.join([
           '*' if cell.value else ' '
           for cell in row
       ])
       for row in self.board_
   ])
   ```
6. You don't need to use the surrounding brackets if your comprehension is the only argument to a function. However, [this may be a couple of u seconds slower](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37782066), which shouldn't matter to most people.

   ```
   return '\n'.join(
       ''.join(
           '*' if cell.value else ' '
           for cell in row
       )
       for row in self.board_
   )
   ```
7. I'd make another function `neighbours`. I find this nicer, as finding the neighbors can be a little annoying, and take away from the actual algorithm.

   I'd also make the algorithm use a premade list, that filters out `x==i` already.

   ```
   NEIGHBOURS = [(i, j) for i in range(-1, 2) for j in range(-1, 2) if i or j]

   def neighbours(self, x: int, y: int) -> Iterator[Tuple[State, int, int]]:
       for i, j in ((x+i, y+j) for i, j in NEIGHBOURS):
           try:
               yield self.board_[i][j], i, j
           except IndexError:
               pass

   def count_live_neighbours(self, x : int, y : int) -> int:
       ''' count the live neighbours of a cell '''
       return sum(cell.value for cell, _, _ in self.neighbours(x, y))
   ```
8. Your `next_cell_state` function can be simplified.

   1. Your two `if`s return `State.ALIVE`.
   2. They can be merged together.
   3. You can return early if `count` is three.
   4. You can simplify the rest of the checks.

   ```
   def next_cell_state(self, x : int, y : int) -> State:
       count = self.count_live_neighbours(x, y)
       if count == 3 or (count == 2 and self.board_[x][y] == State.ALIVE):
           return State.ALIVE
       return State.DEAD
   ```

```
import numpy as np
import time

from enum import Enum
from typing import List, Iterator, Sequence, Tuple


NEIGHBOURS = [(i, j) for i in range(-1, 2) for j in range(-1, 2) if i or j]


class State(Enum):
    ''' enum class to represent possible cell states '''
    DEAD = 0
    ALIVE = 1


class Board:
    ''' Board class to represent the game board '''
    def __init__(self, rows : int, columns : int, init : Sequence[Sequence[int]]):
        self.rows = rows   # the number of rows
        self.columns = columns   # the number of columns
        self.board_ = [
            [
                State(init[i][j])
                for j in range(self.columns)
            ]
            for i in range(self.rows)
        ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        ''' return the __str__ representation of a Board object
            * represents a live cell, and a space represents a dead one
        '''
        return '\n'.join([
            ''.join([
                '*' if cell.value else ' '
                for cell in row
            ])
            for row in self.board_
        ])

    @property
    def population(self) -> int:
        ''' population — the number of live cells on the board '''
        return sum(cell.value for row in self.board_ for cell in row)

    def has_live_cells(self) -> bool:
        ''' return whether there are any live cells or not '''
        return any(cell.value for row in self.board_ for cell in row)

    def neighbours(self, x: int, y: int) -> Iterator[Tuple[State, int, int]]:
        for i, j in ((x+i, y+j) for i, j in NEIGHBOURS):
            try:
                yield self.board_[i, j], i, j
            except IndexError:
                pass

    def count_live_neighbours(self, x : int, y : int) -> int:
        ''' count the live neighbours of a cell '''
        return sum(cell.value for cell, _, _ in self.neighbours(x, y))

    def next_cell_state(self, x : int, y : int) -> State:
        count = self.count_live_neighbours(x, y)
        if count == 3 or (count == 2 and self.board_[x][y] == State.ALIVE):
            return State.ALIVE
        return State.DEAD

    def next_board_state(self) -> List[List[State]]: 
        ''' return board configuration for the next state '''
        return [
            [
                self.next_cell_state(i, j)
                for j in range(self.columns)
            ]
            for i in range(self.rows)
        ]

    def advance_state(self):
        ''' update the board configuration with the config for the next state '''
        self.board_ = self.next_board_state()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.random.choice([0, 1], (20, 100), p=[0.90, 0.1]) 
    board = Board(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1], init=arr.tolist())

    step = 0
    while board.has_live_cells():
        step += 1
        print(board)
        print('f{step} {board.population}')
        board.advance_state()

        time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. A couple of other things. In the same function, you're yielding `self.board_[i, j]`, while I believe you meant `...[i][j]`, but that's a small thing. For consistency, would it also be better for `next_board_state` to hint a return type of `List[List[State]]` or `Sequence[Sequence[State]]`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Wat, IDK why I did that... Thanks :) You can change your returns to use `Sequence`, however I wouldn't. First the docs say not to. "Generic version of `list`. Useful for annotating return types." This is as _abstract collection types_ are, likely, intended to be like _interfaces_ in languages like _C#_. Where `List` is just a _class_. And so you want to work on _interfaces_, and return _classes_ / _interfaces_.

Comment: "6. You don't need to use the surrounding brackets if your comprehension is the only argument to a function.": yes you do, performance is better with the brackets, else it forces `join` to call the gencomp to build a list anyway (so no memory benefits) and it's slower!!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The above code works without the brackets. As far as I see it, if you're using _Python_ you don't really care about a couple of ms, as otherwise you'd be using any other language.

Comment: it _works_ without the brackets, but it works _faster_ with the brackets, so I can't let you suggest to remove something that works faster for the sake of readability, no.